# How to execute a python code based on the condition of last modified date

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements, python-datetime

I want to execute a code, but after a condition that if the modified date is the current date continue, and if the last modified date is not today then quit() the program.

Comment: You've have quite literally spelt out exactly what your 4 lines of code need to do, so you've got the logic all figured out, it just looks like you may need to follow a beginners tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Care to share your draft so it's clearer?
Anyway, get the current date this way:

```
from datetime import date
today_date = date.today()
```

Then you can go on like this:

```
if given_date != today_date:
    exit()
.
.
.
```

Comment: Why did you solve this for him?